# AssertJ check list contains X items but are all null

Tags: assertj

I've looked through the AssertJ examples (https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java) but I can't find an example of: -

1. assert list is of size X e.g. `3`
2. assert all items are `null`

e.g.

```
List<String> items= Arrays.asList(null, null, null);
assertThat(items).hasSize(3).containsOnlyNulls();
```

> Note - `containsOnlyNulls` doesn't exist but this is essentially what I'm trying to test for.  Can this be achieved in AssertJ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either

```
// need to cast to String
assertThat(items).hasSize(3).containsOnly((String) null);
```

or

```
assertThat(items).filteredOn(item -> item == null).hasSize(3);
```

- Edit -

[containsOnlyNulls](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnlyNulls()) assertion has been added to AssertJ in 3.9.0+

Example:

```
// assertion will pass
Iterable<String> items = Arrays.asList(null, null, null);
assertThat(items).containsOnlyNulls();

// assertion will fail because items2 contains a not null element
Iterable<String> items2 = Arrays.asList(null, null, "notNull");
assertThat(items2).containsOnlyNulls();

// assertion will fail since an empty iterable does not contain any elements and therefore no null ones.
Iterable<String> empty = new ArrayList<>();
assertThat(empty).containsOnlyNulls();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Joel!  Are there plans to add new methods in the future like e.g. `containsOnlyNulls` or are these deemed too "bloaty"?

Comment: since we have `containsNull` we can add `containsOnlyNulls`, you are welcome to create the issue in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues

Comment: Done (https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1062) - Kudos on such a great library BTW - been using it this last year and loving it!